# Error while deploying spring boot app on glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I can't deploy WAR of my spring boot app on glassfish 4.1.2. While deploying ApplicationcontextException is thrown, and can't find any working explanation on web.

> [2019-11-27T14:02:57.302+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid:
>   _ThreadID=98 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1574852577302] [levelValue: 800] [[   2019-11-27 14:02:57.302  INFO 592 ---
>   [min-listener(7)] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.]]
>
> [2019-11-27T14:02:57.457+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid:
>   _ThreadID=98 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1574852577457] [levelValue: 800] [[   2019-11-27 14:02:57.456 ERROR 592 ---
>   [min-listener(7)] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               :
>   Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start web server; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]:
>   Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
>   [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:6062)
>   [web-core.jar:na]     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:774)
>   [web-glue.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5960)
>   [web-core.jar:na]     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
>   [web-glue.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
>   [web-core.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
>   [web-core.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
>   [web-core.jar:na]     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
>   [web-glue.jar:na]     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
>   [web-glue.jar:na]     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
>   [web-glue.jar:na]     at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>   [internal-api.jar:na]     at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
>   [internal-api.jar:na]     at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
>   [internal-api.jar:na]     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>   [deployment-admin.jar:na]     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) [na:1.8.0_231]    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360) [na:1.8.0_231]     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) [na:1.8.0_231]    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360) [na:1.8.0_231]     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
>   [rest-service.jar:na]     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
>   [rest-service.jar:na]     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:275)
>   [rest-service.jar:na]     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:133)
>   [rest-service.jar:na]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>   [jersey-server.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>   [jersey-server.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>   [jersey-server.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>   [jersey-server.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>   [jersey-server.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>   [jersey-server.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>   [jersey-server.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>   [jersey-server.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
>   [jersey-server.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>   [jersey-common.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>   [jersey-common.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>   [jersey-common.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>   [jersey-common.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>   [jersey-common.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>   [jersey-common.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
>   [jersey-server.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
>   [jersey-server.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:375)
>   [jersey-container-grizzly2-http.jar:na]   at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
>   [rest-service.jar:na]     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
>   [rest-service.jar:na]     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>   [kernel.jar:na]   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>   [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [na:1.8.0_231] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]:
>   Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:174)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:169)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:154)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    ... 86 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]:
>   Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   ... 104 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final
>   class     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at
>   org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1220)
>   ~[war-util.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1750)
>   ~[war-util.jar:na]    at
>   org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
>   ~[war-util.jar:na]    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module.setupModule(Jdk8Module.java:30)
>   ~[jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:651)
>   ~[jackson-databind.jar:2.5.1]     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModules(ObjectMapper.java:839)
>   ~[jackson-databind.jar:2.5.1]     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.configure(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:665)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:633)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:59)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:76)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.(FormContentFilter.java:61)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter.(OrderedFormContentFilter.java:29)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration.formContentFilter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:161)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]   ... 105 common frames
>   omitted]]

I'm absolutely new at spring, that's why mistake could be everywhere.

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return super.configure(application);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
}

@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message about the bean named `formContentFilter` should have been accompanied by an exception stack trace that shows where the problem occurred. Can you add that to your question please?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson can't paste full trace, is it ok in this edition?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is a verify error that's being thrown by the JVM because a class is trying to extend a class that is `final`. Such code would normally fail at complication time. For it to be failing at runtime means that the version of the class that is being used at runtime is not the same as the version that was used at compile time.

Looking at the stack trace, it's happening on line 30 of Jackson's `Jdk8Module`. This class has been loaded from `jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.0.jar`. 2.10.0 is the version I'd expect with Spring Boot 2.2.1 so that part looks ok. Further down the stack trace I can see that Jackson's `ObjectMapper` has been loaded from `jackson-databind.jar:2.5.1`. 2.5.1 is unexpected and should be 2.10.0 so that the versions of Jackson's modules all match up. I suspect that this is the source of the incompatibility.

The problem could be in your application and you're packaging a mixture of versions in your war file. Alternatively, your war file could be fine and contain only Jackson 2.10.0 jars and the problem is caused by Glassfish polluting the classpath with an old version of Jackson. You can check the contents of your war file using `jar -tf yourapp.war` and looking at what's in `WEB-INF/lib`. If the problem's there, you'll need to update your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` to correct the mismatched versions. If the problem's not there you'll need to configure Glassfish to prefer your application's version of Jackson over its own. You can do that with a `WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` file with contents similar to the following:

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
        <class-loader delegate="false"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```